# Delay after addpoint when y-axis with opposite: true

Tags: highcharts

I want to make a chart by adding many points with series.addPoint( [xTime, yValue], true, true);
Everything works fine, but if the chart is so big that the whole container is filled and I use opposite:true for the y-axis, the last point is always missing but will be shown, when the next point has been added.
Without opposite:true I can see that the points are all correctly added, but I have to put the y-axis to the right. I tried to increase the offset, but this didn't solve the problem.

How can I show the last point?

Comment: Could you reproduce your chart in the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/TFHEu/1/

In the right corner, the actual y value is displayed. As you can see, the chart is displayed correctly until it reaches the right margin. Afterwords the chart is always one step behind.

```
var prevY = 0;
var data = [];
var time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;
// Getting first data, show as diagonals
for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
    data.push({
        x: time + i * 1000,
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * 11)
    });
}
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global : {
                useUTC : false
            },
            lang: {
                months: ['Jan.', 'Feb.', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Aug.', 'Sep.', 'Okt.', 'Nov.', 'Dez.'],
                weekdays: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
                decimalPoint: ',',
                thousandsSep: '.'
            },
            chart : {
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    align: 'left'
                }
            },
            navigator: {
                enabled: true,
                top: 388,
                outlineColor: '#C0C0C0',
                outlineWidth: 1
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: true,
                xDateFormat: '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },                                          
            title: {
                text : ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                lineColor: '#EEEEEE',
                tickColor: '#EEEEEE',
                gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE',
                minorGridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                minRange: 1 * 60 * 1000,
                range: 3 * 60 * 1000,
                labels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                lineColor: '#EEEEEE',
                tickColor: '#EEEEEE',           
                gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE',               
                opposite: true,
                offset: 5,
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickWidth: 1,
                tickInterval: 1,                                        
                minorGridLineColor: '#FFFFFF', 
                minorTickInterval: 'auto',
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
             minorTickColor: '#FFFFFF',
             minorTickWidth: 1,
             endOnTick: false,
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 1,',','.');
                    }                   
                }                   
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    threshold: null,
                    showInLegend : false,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        radius: 2
                    }
                }
            }

        }); 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var chart = this;
                        var series = this.series[0];                                
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var xTime = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time                         
                            var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 11);
                            data.push([ xTime, prevY ]);                                    
                            data.push([ xTime, y ]);
                            series.setData(data, true);
                            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes( chart.xAxis[0].min, chart.xAxis[0].max);
                            document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = y;
                            prevY = y;
                        }, 3 * 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'series',
                type : 'area',
                color: 'rgba(026, 089, 184, 1)',
                fillColor: 'rgba(200, 221, 251, 0.5)', // nicht mit # Hexcode angeben, sonst funktioniert Opacity (Durchsichtigkeit) nicht                
                data: data
            }]
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: The reason is lineWidth for yAxis which will cover up most right point line, when set lineWidth: 0, it works fine.